# 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'sort'

Tags: python

Estou tentando criar um programa para ler o conjunto de dados, ordená-lo por colunas e depois remover valores atípicos, mas minha função não está funcionando, porque estou usando uma nova versão do numpy 0.25, portanto a classificação não funciona, alguém pode me ajudar com esse problema?

```
def remove_outlier(df):
list = ['Unnamed: 32', 'diagnosis', 'id']
x = df.drop(list, axis=1)
# x.head()

# df = x.sort_values
x.sort(axis=0) **<---- HERE IS THE PROBLEM, I THINK**
x = pd.DataFrame(df, index=x.index, columns=x.columns)
x.loc[:, :]
print(x)

Q1 = x.quantile(0.25)
Q3 = x.quantile(0.75)
IQR = Q3 - Q1
print(IQR)

number_outliers = (x < (Q1 - 1.5 * IQR)) | (x > (Q3 + 1.5 * IQR))
number_outliers.head(-1)

remove_outliers = x[~((x < (Q1 - 1.5 * IQR)) | (x > (Q3 + 1.5 * IQR))).any(axis=1)]
df1 = remove_outliers.head(-1)
return df1
```

Comment: Olá @vinicius reis tudo bem? Faça sua pergunta em português para podermos te ajudar.

Answer (score 0):

O `DataFrame.sort` é obsoleto desde a versão 0.19 (creio que foi a partir desta https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort.html) e creio que nas versões posteriores já foi removido.

Deve-se usar `DataFrame.sort_values()` que é o seu equivalente:

- https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html?highlight=sort#pandas.DataFrame.sort_values

Comment: to ligado Guilherme Nascimento, o problema é que eu não consigo implementar o sort_values nessa função de jeito nenhum

Comment: @viniciusreis respondi conforme o erro da pergunta, se falhou em usar sort_values isso não foi descrito na pergunta e apenas dizer "não consegui" não dá informações suficientes para eu conseguir te ajudar, deve dizer aonde falou ou se ocorreu algum exception.